# How to enumerate available database Services(SQLSewrver or Oracle or MySQL or PostgreSQL, etc) in a network in C#?

Tags: c#

How to enumerate available database Services(SQL Server or Oracle or MySQL or PostgreSQL, etc) in a network using C#?

I also need to find their port-numbers and service-instance names.

For example:

```
class Server
{
    #region DLL Inports
    [DllImport("odbc32.dll")]
    private static extern short SQLAllocHandle(short hType, IntPtr inputHandle, out IntPtr outputHandle);
    [DllImport("odbc32.dll")]
    private static extern short SQLSetEnvAttr(IntPtr henv, int attribute, IntPtr valuePtr, int strLength);
    [DllImport("odbc32.dll")]
    private static extern short SQLFreeHandle(short hType, IntPtr handle);
    [DllImport("odbc32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private static extern short SQLBrowseConnect(IntPtr hconn, StringBuilder inString,
        short inStringLength, StringBuilder outString, short outStringLength,
        out short outLengthNeeded);
    #endregion

    #region Constants
    private const short SQL_HANDLE_ENV = 1;
    private const short SQL_HANDLE_DBC = 2;
    private const int SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION = 200;
    private const int SQL_OV_ODBC3 = 3;
    private const short SQL_SUCCESS = 0;
    private const short SQL_NEED_DATA = 99;
    private const short DEFAULT_RESULT_SIZE = 1024;
    private const string SQL_DRIVER_STR = "DRIVER=SQL SERVER";
    #endregion

    #region static string[] GetServers()
    public static string[] GetNames()
    {
        string[] retval = null;
        string txt = string.Empty;
        IntPtr henv = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr hconn = IntPtr.Zero;
        StringBuilder inString = new StringBuilder(SQL_DRIVER_STR);
        StringBuilder outString = new StringBuilder(DEFAULT_RESULT_SIZE);
        short inStringLength = (short)inString.Length;
        short lenNeeded = 0;

        try
        {
            if (SQL_SUCCESS == SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, henv, out henv))
            {
                if (SQL_SUCCESS == SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (IntPtr)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0))
                {
                    if (SQL_SUCCESS == SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, henv, out hconn))
                    {
                        if (SQL_NEED_DATA == SQLBrowseConnect(hconn, inString, inStringLength, outString,
                            DEFAULT_RESULT_SIZE, out lenNeeded))
                        {
                            if (DEFAULT_RESULT_SIZE < lenNeeded)
                            {
                                outString.Capacity = lenNeeded;
                                if (SQL_NEED_DATA != SQLBrowseConnect(hconn, inString, inStringLength, outString,
                                    lenNeeded, out lenNeeded))
                                {
                                    throw new ApplicationException("Unabled to aquire SQL Servers from ODBC driver.");
                                }
                            }
                            txt = outString.ToString();
                            int start = txt.IndexOf("{") + 1;
                            int len = txt.IndexOf("}") - start;
                            if ((start > 0) && (len > 0))
                            {
                                txt = txt.Substring(start, len);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                txt = string.Empty;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Throw away any error if we are not in debug mode
            //#if (DEBUG)
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Acquire SQL Servier List Error");
            //#endif 
            txt = string.Empty;

            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (hconn != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hconn);
            }
            if (henv != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hconn);
            }
        }

        if (txt.Length > 0)
        {
            retval = txt.Split(",".ToCharArray());
        }

        return retval;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

This code only works for SqlServers and up to WindowsXP.

It doesn't work for other DBMS Servers and on Win7.

I am in need of a canonical solution.

Comment: I nearly marked this as belongs on Server Fault but I think what would be better in this case is to ask the same question on Server Fault without the language specified so you can get a generic answer which you should be able to translate into C#.

Comment: How do you define "Database Server"?

Comment: Any specific vendor? Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server?

Comment: No specific vendor. Any RDBMS.

Comment: i do hope you arent a cracker.  why not send a mail to the admins?

Comment: If the question is for all RDBMS, then the answer is no. There is no such thing as an "RDBMS discovery protocol" standard that would apply to all. You can only use heuristics (scan ports, try to connect to sockets, try some data, etc.) - hoping that you won't be seen as a hacker.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [SqlDataSourceEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.aspx) class for this as well.  Keep in mind, this is MS SQL Server specific...

```
var results = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();

foreach (var row in results.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\{1}", row["ServerName"], row["InstanceName"]);
}
```

See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6t1z9x2.aspx) for additional info

Comment: See my comment in my previous answer.

Comment: my answer is MS SQL specific.  If you wanted to scan for *any* type of server, you'd have to know how to query for each one.  Oracle, DB2, MySql likely all expose something similar - you'd just have to combine each of those with this code to scan for all of the above.  Like David Anderson said in the other comments - this should just give you a start...

Answer (score 2):

> Does it work for any RDBMS Server?

Your answer is always going to be "no" here. Every RDBMS lets you set up a custom port - MySQL could be on 1433 or 1434 or 99999. Every RDBMS responds differently from other RDBMSes and even sometimes from previous versions of itself... You'd have to check every networking port possible on every computer for every RDBMS (and every version of that RDBMS if they change response strings often) and HOPE they have them configured with standard plaintext responses instead of being encrypted or whatnot. This is basic networking - first you portscan the IP range, then you can try to appscan on the active ports you've found to see how they respond to various requests, then you use that information to say "these IPs have apps that appear to be databases on the following ports" -- you're still not going to get things like MS Instance Name without going through the proper channels (as listed with code samples above).

Your best bet for understanding where to start is probably - http://www.nmap.org

Answer (score 2):

To combine things said in the previous answers / comments:

Contact your sysadmin, becasue this is undoable. You would need to account for every version of every (R)DBMS out there (or at least the latest ones).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other responses:

I have found `Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataSourceEnumerator` in the `Oracle.DataAccess` dll (`Oracle.DataAccess.client`)

By adding `Oracle.managment.omo.dll` and `DataAccess.dll`,you can manipulate Oracle objects like sql;management.SMO in MS SQLSERVER

Answer (score 1):

Resources:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6C3E9EF-BA29-4A43-8D69-A2BED18FE73C&displaylang=en

You would want to look into SMO. This requires each client to have the Sql Management Objects and CLR types installed. Below is a code snippet from one of my working applications that does just this.

```
private void OnClicked_RefreshDataSources(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        DataTable dt = SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(false);
        uxDataSource.Items.Clear();

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
            uxDataSource.Items.Add(row["Name"]);
        }

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
            uxDataSource.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }

    private void OnSelectedIndexChanged_PopulateDatabases(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ConnectionString.DataSource = uxDataSource.SelectedItem.ToString();

        Server server = new Server(uxDataSource.SelectedItem.ToString());
        server.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = false;
        server.ConnectionContext.Login = Program.DesktopService.AccountName;

        uxInitialCatalog.Items.Clear();

        try {
            foreach (Database db in server.Databases) {
                uxInitialCatalog.Items.Add(db.Name);
            }

            if (server.Databases.Count > 0) {
                uxInitialCatalog.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
        catch {
            MessageBox.Show("You do not have access to this server.", "Sql Connection", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            uxInitialCatalog.Items.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I doubt it. This is strictly Sql Server code, but gives you a good start at what you're looking for. I would assume if you're looking for other types of databases, that those server's may expose an API similar to this